# How exactly is the print statement working in these two methods?

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, tree

This is wrt to Binary Search Tree.I  am traversing the tree in 2 ways.1)InOrder Traversal 
An inorder traversal of tree t is a recursive algorithm that follows the the left subtree; once there are no more left subtrees to process, we process the right subtree. The elements are processed in left-root-right order. 
2)PostOrder Traversal 
A postorder traversal of tree t is a recursive algorithm that follows the the left and right subtrees before processing the root element. The elements are processed left-right-root order.

I am confused over how the recursion methods and print statements are working. Could you please enlighten me?

```
static void inOrder(Leaf root){
    if(root != null){
        inOrder(root.left);
        System.out.print(root.value+" ");
        inOrder(root.right);
    }
}
static void postOrder(Leaf root){
    if(root != null){
        postOrder(root.left);
        postOrder(root.right);
        System.out.print(root.value+" ");
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is problem with it? Hint: The best way would be to draw some trees on a sheet of paper and travers them by hand.

Comment: Also you can try implementing the iterative code. It will give you an good idea about how the recursion stack works.

Answer (score 1):

The way this works is each function will print out a single, long line containing each of the values if the tree.  As each of the algorithms goes through the tree, it appends the current value of the node to the output along with a space.  For example, if we consider the following tree:

```
  2
 / \
1   3
```

The first algorithm will start at the 2, then call itself on the left child, 1.  The function will then call itself on the left child, which is null, so it will return immediately.  The function will then print "1 " to the console.  The function will call itself on the right child, which is null, so it will return immediately.  The function will then return to the 2, and "2 " will be printed to the console.  The function will then call itself on the right child, which is the 3.  The function will call itself on the left child , which returns, then print "3 " to the console, then call itself on the right child, which returns.  The function will then return to the 2, and that will return to whatever called it.  The console at the end will say

```
1 2 3
```

A similar thing would happen for the second algorithm, except the function would go to and print the left and right children, 1 and 3, respectively, before printing the root node, 2, resulting in the following output:

```
1 3 2
```

If you are having trouble understanding it, it would benefit you to draw yourself a tree and follow the code step by step to see what the computer is doing.

Answer (score 0):

As every recursion method, it needs a base case, a condition to stop the recursion. In this case, it's when "root" is null.

Observe that the variable root, will only be the actual root of the Tree at the first call in the method. Consecutive calls are passing the element on it's left or right.

On the method inOrder, it prints the elements that are further down on the left branch of the Tree. So it "goes down a level" on the tree before calling the print. This means that if the element has a leaf on a left branch, it will print said leaf before going to the right branch.

in the postOrder Method, it will go the furthest down on the tree it can go and then print the elements, doing that for both branches ( left and right ). This meaning that the leafs of thre tree will be printed first while the actual root will be the last Element.

If you're having trouble visualizing, i suggest you draw the tree in a paper and run the code with a small sample tree using the Debug on Eclipse, so you can follow the execution line by line and see how the algorithm is traversing the Tree.